# Extract SQS Queue Message in Lambda Function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have an SQS queue which triggers my Lambda function. I am trying to parse the SQS message and extract relevant data. I am specifically trying to extract the s3 object key and the s3 bucket arn.

My current Lambda function:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
       
    for record in event['Records']:
        payload = record['body']
        print(str(payload))

        objectKey = record['body']['s3']['object']['key']
        bucketARN = record['body']['s3']['bucket']['arn']
        
        print('Filename is: ' + str(objectKey))
        print('Bucket ARN is: ' + str(bucketARN))
```

My SQS message that is shown in CloudWatch:

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "eventVersion": "2.1",
            "eventSource": "aws:s3",
            "awsRegion": "xxx",
            "eventTime": "2021-03-27T19:39:41.694Z",
            "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
            "userIdentity": {
                "principalId": "AWS:AIDAQ5MMP4GQL2S4KQ2SZ"
            },
            "requestParameters": {
                "sourceIPAddress": "xxx"
            },
            "responseElements": {
                "x-amz-request-id": "xxx",
                "x-amz-id-2": "xxx"
            },
            "s3": {
                "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
                "configurationId": "xxx",
                "bucket": {
                    "name": "xxx",
                    "ownerIdentity": {
                        "principalId": "AHWVPEVW911DW"
                    },
                    "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::xxx"
                },
                "object": {
                    "key": "Audio1.mp3",
                    "size": 16659,
                    "eTag": "71d5ea0a7152e04d0d170be8146080ba",
                    "sequencer": "00605F8A02147F848A"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And lastly the error I'm being given:

```
[ERROR] TypeError: string indices must be integers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/transcribe.py", line 14, in lambda_handler
    objectKey = record['body']['s3']['object']['key']
```

I have also tried objectKey = record['Records][0]['s3']['object']['key'].
Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `record['s3']['object']['key']`? You can debug via `print(record)` and see what it contains.

Comment: You might want to use: `objectKey = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(record['s3']['object']['key']))`

Answer (score 0):

Found a helpful answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61043849/parse-sqs-message-trigger-in-aws-lambda-python?rq=1).

This worked for me:

```
for record in event['Records']:     
        #pull the body out & json load it
        jsonmaybe = record['body']
        jsonmaybe = json.loads(jsonmaybe)
        
        objectKey = jsonmaybe['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
        print(objectKey)
        bucketARN = jsonmaybe['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['arn']
        print(bucketARN)
```